# A field is factorial (UFD)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Definition: A factorial ring (or unique factorization domain abbreviated UFD) is an
integral domain A satisfying the following properties:
a) Existence: Every nonzero element x of A, has a decomposition into irreducible factors
of the form
x = u p1    pn
where n 2 N, u is an invertible element of A and p1; : : : ; pn are irreducible elements
of A.
b) Uniqueness: If a nonzero element x has two factorizations:
x = u p1    pn and x = v q1    qm
where m; n 2 N, u and v are invertible in A and p1; : : : ; pn; q1; : : : ; qm are
irreducible elements of A, then n = m and there exists a permutation  2 Sn such
that pj is associated to q(j) for all 1  j  n. In other words, the decomposition
into irreducible factors in A is unique up to the order of the irreducible factors.

Every field is a factorial ring. why??

Comment: Every nonzero element is a unit, its principal ideal is the whole field.

Comment: The definition of a factorial ring is that every element has a decomposition into irreducible factors (non unit elements) but all the elements of a field are nonunits. Thus a field cant be a factorial ring

Comment: There are no irreducible elements of a field. Take $n=0$ in the definition, just as for $x=1$ in any ring. All nonzero elements are units.

Comment: The point of questions like this is to see if you understand the definitions.  If you can't answer immediately, you should look up the definitions and match things up.  You will find just one or a couple things need to be proved.

Comment: Every nonzero element in a field is a unit $u$ so existence of prime factorizations is trivial, viz. $u$ = $u$ times an *empty* product of primes $(= 1)$. Uniqueness is also trivial since there are no nonunits, so no irreducibles or primes..

Answer (score 2):

In any commutative ring, divisibility is actually a *preorder* (reflexive and transitive relation), which determines an equivalence relation, namely $a\sim b\iff a\,|\,b\ \land\  b\,|\,a$.

It can be easily shown that an element $u$ is a unit (has multiplicative inverse) iff $u\sim 1$, and using this, (at least in an integral domain) we get $a\sim b\iff b=ua$ for some unit $u$.

In $\Bbb Z$ the only units are $+1$ and $-1$. And we mostly *don't care* them in divisibility or factorization questions, they are just side effects, like the sign of an integer.

A field has *no* irreducible elements, each nonzero element is invertible, hence a unit, so the definition for $x\ne0$ holds with $u=x$ and $n=0$.

Note that we must allow $n=0$ because the $1$ in any ring has no irreducible factors.